# How to extract IF (instantaneous frequency) from Discrete Hilbert Transform?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, transform, hilbert-transform

The continuous time Hilbert transform is
$$\hat x(t) := x(t) + j\left( p.v. \left\{\frac{1}{t\pi} \ast x \right\} (t)\right)$$

where
$$ \theta(t) = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{ p.v.  \left\{\frac{1}{t\pi} \ast x \right\} (t)}{x(t)} \right)$$
and
$$
         \omega(t) = \theta'(t) 
$$

and since $\theta(t)$ is smooth, you can actually calculate the instantaneous frequency. But in the discrete time domain, the angle function is discrete, so given that in the dt domain, your hilbert transform filter is

$$ h_{HT}[n] = \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
       \frac{1}{n\pi}  & \mbox{if}\ \  n \neq 0 \\
        0               & \mbox{otherwise} \\
      \end{array}
     \right.$$

How do you get the approximate frequency? or are you really just getting $\Delta\theta[n]$? Sorry if this is me just getting hung up on something trivial, but most references don't seem to clearly address this.

$$\theta[n] = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(h_{HT} \ast x)[n]}{x[n]}\right)$$
$$\omega[n] = \left\{
       \begin{array}{ll}
        \theta[n] \ast \frac{1}{T_s}(\delta[n] - \delta[n-1])  & ? \\
        \theta[n] \ast \frac{1}{2T_s}(\delta[n+1] - \delta[n-1])  & ? \\
        ???
       \end{array}
      \right.
$$

I'm looking for what is typically done. The "Standard" approach.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase#Instantaneous_frequency)? They also explain it for the discrete-time case, which seems to equal your first option for $\omega[n]$.

Comment: @MattL. Good enough for me. Didn't think to check IF on wikipedia.

Comment: There's also a [paper by Barnes](ftp://ftp.ecn.purdue.edu/ayhan/Jeffrey/Calculation%20of%20instantaneous%20frequency%20and%20instantaneous%20bandwidth.pdf) discussing several options for sampled data. See the section on IF approximations.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! I did a basic literature search before asking, I swear. But i was looking mostly at HT & HHT references, not IF references, so maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: you have a curious mix of discrete and continuous-time expressions that should get ironed out.  regarding this:
$$\theta[n] = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(h_{HT} \ast x)[n]}{x[n]}\right)$$
$$\omega[n] = \left\{
       \begin{array}{ll}
        \theta[n] \ast \frac{1}{T_s}(\delta[n] - \delta[n-1])  & ? \\
        \theta[n] \ast \frac{1}{2T_s}(\delta[n+1] - \delta[n-1])  & ? \\
        ???
       \end{array}
      \right.
$$  you need to look into designing a digital differentiator, if you want to do this the best.  however, your first expression is likely okay.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I'm not sure I follow. Those  are all discrete-time expressions. I realize I was asking for how to design  a discrete-time differentiator. My question was which one was "standard".

Comment: also, regarding the paper by Barnes that @MattL. referred to, you should note well Eq (3) in which the derivative is carried *through* the $\arctan()$ function.  there is a discrete counterpart to that (using a trig identity for $\arctan(a-b)$) which i have to either re-derive or look up.  so you can compute either instantaneous frequency or group delay **without** having to unwrap a phase explicitly.  you might be computing an $\arctan(\Delta\theta)$ for small $\Delta\theta$, but that's a well-behaved function.

Comment: oh, you're right.  at first glance, i thought the convolution with $h_{HT}$ was continuous.  if $h_{HT}$ is discrete, it should be: $$ h_{HT}[n] = \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{2 \pi n} \cdot w[n] $$ where $w[n]$ is a suitable window function.

Comment: oh, hey that's different than the $h_{HT}[n]$ i found elsewhere.  Is that derived somewhere?

Comment: There are two types of discrete-time Hilbert transformers. The one that @robertbristow-johnson wrote down in his comment (just the factor $2$ in the denominator is not quite right), and the other one is $$h_{HT}[n]=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ After windowing, the first one becomes a type III linear phase filter (odd length, odd symmetry), the other one becomes a type IV linear phase FIR filter (even length, odd symmetry). The first one (odd length) is of course cheaper to implement because every other sample is zero. The even length filter is better at frequencies close to Nyquist.

Comment: yah, you're right.  i could plausibly deny it's wrong and claim it's how $w[n]$ is defined, but instead i was thinking that $1-(-1)^{2n+1}$ adds to 2.  i sorta forgot that it still averages to 1.  um, one reason i like the other one better is that, being a halfband filter, we can make the FIR twice as long (for the same cost in non-zero taps) when we know that half the taps are zero.  but, you're right, the $2$ should be gone and $w[n] \le 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a nice solution for you that I'm always using whenever I need to compute the instantaneous frequency of a discrete analytical signal and which works much better then the common approach using $tan(.)$ where you need to introduce thresholds and fiddle around with adding/subtracting $2\pi$. In addition to that it is even faster.

Given a signal $x(t)$ and the corresponding analytical signal $$\xi(t) = x(t) + i\mathcal{H}x(t)$$ with $\mathcal{H}$ being the hilbert transform operator the instantaneous frequency $\omega(t)$ can be computed as followed. We have $\omega(t)=\dot{\varphi}(t)$ with $\varphi(t)=\Im log\xi(t)$ being the phase of the analytical signal $\xi$ ($\Im$ denotes the imaginary part). Combining these equations we get
$$
\omega(t)=\Im\frac{d}{dt}log\xi(t)=\Im\frac{\dot{\xi}(t)}{\xi(t)}
$$
This can also be seen be as follows:
$$
  \Im\frac{\dot{\xi}}{\xi} = \Im\frac{ \dot{A}e^{i\varphi} + iAe^{i\varphi}\dot{\varphi} }{Ae^{i\varphi}}
                       = \Im\Big[ \frac{\dot{A}}{A} + i\dot{\varphi} \Big]
                       = \dot{\varphi}
$$
Discretizing this equation you can now compute the discrete instantaneous frequency from the discrete analytical signal:
$$ \omega[n]\approx\Im\frac{\xi[n+1]-\xi[n]}{\xi[n]} $$
or second order:
$$ \omega[n]\approx\Im\frac{\xi[n+1]-\xi[n-1]}{2\xi[n]} $$

Of course this is not *the* exact solution as it is still requires a discrete differentiation of the signal. But this could be done using standard techniques.

Comment: Cool! That does look faster without the $\tan^{-1}$.